# how do i save data to a text file mainly what i have written in record

Tags: python

New to python, need to store this data to a text file. mainly my record but comes up with concat error (tuple) in the recsave.write line. any help or suggestions or just done completely wrong

```
print (' Title ')
name = 'y'

while name == 'y':

    print (' Enter the name of the sender: ')
    sender = input("\n")

     # add name of reciever #
    print (' Enter the name of the reciever: ')
    reciever = input("\n")

     # how much would you like to send # 
    print (' How much would you like to send :$ ')
    amount = input("\n")

    record = (sender, 'sent :$',amount, 'to', reciever, "\n" )

    recsave = open('Transaction History.txt', 'w')

    recsave.write(record + '\n')
    recsave.close()

    print (str(record, "\n"))

    name = input (' Are there anymore transactions? ( Enter y or n ): ')
```

would like to get it so when open the text file. you get

name sent $amount to name

also needs to include time stamp :( 
aslo each time the loop runs saves each loop to the record

Comment: format one string with your informationa and write it.

Comment: maybe better use module `logging` to write it - it will add timestamp automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create one string with all information instead of tuple and write it

```
import datetime

dt = datetime.datetime.now()
record = "{} : {} sent :${} to {}\n".format(dt, sender, amount, reciever)

recsave = open('Transaction History.txt', 'a')
recsave.write(record)
recsave.close()

print(record)
```

Use mode `"a"` (append) instead of `"w"` (write) to add new record to existing records in file.
`w` will remove old information.

In record you add `"\n"` so you don't have to add it in `write()`

---

But you could create function to do it and then you can use it in different places

```
import datetime

def log(message):
    dt = datetime.datetime.now()

    line = "{} : {}\n".format(dt, message)

    recsave = open('Transaction History.txt', 'a')
    recsave.write(line)
    recsave.close()

    print(line)

#----

log("start program")

record = "{} sent :${} to {}".format(dt, sender, amount, reciever)
log(record)

log("end program")
```

---

There is standard module [logging](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/logging.html) to create log or file with history.

Comment: Thanks alot furas. greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I added example with function and link to logging - see also https://realpython.com/python-logging/

Comment: you can also use date from datetime to create filename with date - ie. `"history-2019-04-16.log"`